# How to have child div not trigger hover effect of parent div?

Tags: html, css, inheritance, hover

I am trying to find out how to have a child element that has `position: absolute` that is positioned outside of its parent element that does not trigger the parent's `:hover` effect.

Since the parent has a hover effect, the child elements will  trigger the parent element, even though that child is outside of the parent element's boundary.

Is there an attribute I am missing, or is this just the way inheritance in HTML works?

[Picture Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WcjEC.png):

[image]

In this image, my mouse cursor is inside the child div, but outside of the parent div.

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.container {
  background-color: black;
  width: 800px;
  aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;
}

.container:hover {
  background-color: darkorange;
}

.child {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  transform: translate(-50px, 0px);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use following solutions for this.

1. You can use `pointer-events: none` on the child element. But remember that this will block all types of pointer events on that, and not just `hover` event. So any sort of click events will also not work on that child element.
2. Another option is to use `:has()` method in the css. `:has()` allows you to target an element that meets the conditions passed to it. You can do it like this -

```css
  .container:not(:has(.child:hover)):hover {
    background-color: darkorange;
  }
```

This will prevent the hover effect on container when hovered over its child element, which is specified in the `:has()` method.
Here is the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hLagp62n/) example demonstrating this method.
Read more about `:has()` in [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has)

Answer (score 0):

You can add `pointer-event: none;` to the child element, which makes it not trigger any mouse events, including mouse hover.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <head>    
    <style>
       body { 
         display: flex; 
         align-items: center;
         justify-content: center; 
       } 
       .container { 
         background-color: black;
         width: 800px; 
         aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;
       } 
       .container:hover { 
         background-color: darkorange; 
       } 
       .child {
         position: absolute; 
         background-color: red; 
         width: 100px;
         height: 100px;
         transform: translate(-50px, 0px);
         pointer-event: none;
       }
   </style>
 </head> 
<body> 
  <div class="container">        
    <div class="child"></div>   
  </div> 
</body>
```